Обработка формы и вызов функции удаления
Из-за своей неопытности не знаю как реализовать обработку формы, чтобы при вводе и нажатии кнопки вызывалась функция DeleteEmployee(). Хотелось бы помощи от опытных разработчиков.
@page "/test"
 
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory
 
<h3>Сотрудники</h3>
 
@if (errorMessage != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @errorMessage
    </div>
}
<div class="form_container">
    <form method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Удалить сотрудника</legend>
             <label for="id">ID сотрудника:</label>
             <input type="text" name="id" value="" />
            <input type="submit" value="Удалить" class="submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>ФИО</th>
            <th>Дата рождения</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (items == null)
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">Loading...</td>
            </tr>
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Id</td>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Birthday.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
@code {
    private List<Classes.Employee> items;
    private string errorMessage;
    private async Task load()
    {
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("MyAPI");
        try
        {
            items = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Classes.Employee>>("api/testapi");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessage = "Не удалось загрузить данные: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
 
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await load();
    }
 
    private async Task DeleteEmployee()
    {
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("MyAPI");    
        Console.WriteLine("Вы пытаетесь удалить сотрудника с ID: "+id);
    }
}

